# How to include php-generated javascript?

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script

I've looked around and have found no great solution so far: I would like to add customized javascript from a widget using `wp_enqueue_script`, but Wordpress seems to be limiting scope to the javascript file I load in, as my javascript file says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'photogallery'

Here is the output I would like to load in, as if it were its own script via `wp_enqueue_script`:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                "use strict";
                $(function () {
                    var $gallery = $("#gallery").photogallery(
                            "a",
                            {
                                thumbs: <?php echo setBool($instance["hasThumbs"]); ?>,
                                history: <?php echo setBool($instance["historyEnabled"]); ?>,
                                time: <?php echo ($instance["transitionTime"] * 1000); ?>,
                                autoplay: <?php echo setBool($instance["autoplayEnabled"]); ?>,
                                loop: <?php echo setBool($instance["isLooped"]); ?>,
                                counter: <?php echo setBool($instance["hasCounter"]); ?>,
                                zoomable: <?php echo setBool($instance["zoomable"]); ?>,
                                hideFlash: <?php echo setBool($instance["hideFlash"]); ?>
                            }
                        );
                });
            }(jQuery));
        </script>
```

I know that manually coding the default values in to another js file, and using `enqueue_script` will work fine, but how do I do this properly, with custom widget values, and not load the required js file twice?  I am not interested in complex ajax requests unless it is my only option, [as mentioned here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either not use `wp_enqueue_script` (which loads a JS file, where you won't be able to use PHP) and instead simply print the script out on the `wp_head` or `wp_footer` hooks.... or you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );

$instance = // not sure how you are fetching this value

$array = array( 'thumbs' => $instance["hasThumbs"], 
                'history' => $instance["historyEnabled"],
                'time' => $instance["transitionTime"] * 1000,
                'autoplay' => $instance["autoplayEnabled"]),
                'loop' => $instance["isLooped"]),
                'counter' => $instance["hasCounter"]),
                'zoomable' => $instance["zoomable"]),
                'hideFlash' => $instance["hideFlash"] );

wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $array );
```

and then you'd modify your JS file to pull the values from the JS object called 'object_name' where the object's properties correspond to the array keys from `wp_localize_script'

```
(function ($) {
                "use strict";
                $(function () {
                    var $gallery = $("#gallery").photogallery(
                            "a",
                            {
                                thumbs: object_name.hasThumbs,
                                history: object_name.history,
                                time: object_name.time,
                                autoplay: object_name.autoplay,
                                loop: object_name.loop,
                                counter: object_name.counter,
                                zoomable: object_name.zoomable,
                                hideFlash: object_name.hideFlash
                            }
                        );
                });
            }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Wowwow, cool.  I will try and post if this works...